# Use of the word "panic-stricken" for self

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, vocabulary, sentence, syntactic-analysis

which would be the correct use of the word "panic-stricken" in the two sentences below:

> I was panic-stricken at the thought of missing my trip to usa

OR

> I got panic-stricken at the thought of missing my trip to usa

Also, please explain why! Because I'm trying to improve my English vocabulary and usage of words in everyday English.

Thank you

Comment: The use of *get* and its various forms in this sense is not formal English. The sentences are acceptable in conversation and in informal writing. See also: [ell.se]

Comment: **get** *v.intr.* **1. a.** To become or grow to be: *eventually got well.* http://www.thefreedictionary.com/get

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct answer is "was". You use a conjugation of the verb "to be" to describe your state.

You use the verb "to get" to describe the action of obtaining an object.

Comment: But then why the sentence "He got hurt" is correct ?
Shouldn't it be "He was hurt" ?

Answer (score 1):

Because "panic-stricken" is an adjective, it makes more sense the first way. Similar to the word "red," you wouldn't say "The car *got* red," you would say "the car *was* red." As the other answer mentions, you use "get" to refer to obtaining something. In your example, you might say "I got a ticket to fly to the USA." As you'll notice, in this example, you are retrieving a ticket. Thus, "got" is appropriate.

Realistically, anyone would understand you either way, of course, and it wouldn't surprise me to hear native speakers saying the latter, but the first one is correct.

Also, as a side note, in proper English you would say "...my trip to **the** USA," as compared to your "my trip to USA." I only bring that up since you said you wanted to get used to the language more. It's not a big deal, and it's certainly a confusing rule, but we refer to the United States, as I did just now, as "*the* United States," not just "United States." That is, of course, different from how we refer to "Canada" or most other countries.

Comment: But then why the sentence "He got hurt" is correct ? Shouldn't it be "He was hurt" ?

Comment: In that example, "hurt" is acting as a past-tense verb. It's similar to saying "He got promoted." It's a bit confusing, I know, because "hurt" is the present and past tense of the verb, as well as the adjective that relates to it. "He was hurt" would also be acceptable, although you don't hear it as much. It also carries a notion of being a longer-running event. For instance, "he couldn't play soccer for a while because he was hurt," makes sense, and so does "he got hurt playing soccer."

Comment: I see. Yes, it's confusing. Especially for a non-native speaker. I am about to give an English test so I am more concern about this type of grammatical mistakes.

Comment: Well your English is very good, for what that's worth. You might want to poke around the [ELL Stack exchange](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) a bit, too. It might be below your proficiency level, but it's possible that you could find some good tips on there.

Comment: Thank you. Oh, I was unaware about ELL stack exchange. That'll definitely help some instant tips. 

Thank you for your help!